# How to solve SQL Server Error 1222 i.e Unlock a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, locking, deadlock

I am working in a database where I load data in a raw table by a data loader. But today the data loader got stuck for unknown reasons. Then I stopped the data loader from windows task manager. But then I again tried to load data in the raw table but found its locked and I can't do any operation on it. I tried restarting SQL Server service but it was not resolved. And I have no permission to kill processes on this server.

Below is the message showed by SQL Server.

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   queries)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject.RenameImplWorker(String
>   newName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.NamedSmoObject.RenameImpl(String
>   newName)
>
> ===================================
>
> Lock request time out period exceeded. Either the parameter @objname
>   is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong. (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ---
>
> Server Name: 162.44.25.59 
>   Error Number: 1222
>   Severity: 16 State: 56
>   Procedure: sp_rename Line Number: 282

My SQL Server version is 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you try killing the session id which has locked the table? You can check it in the SQL Server Activity Monitor on the server or use combination of sp_lock2 and sp_who to find which session needs to be killed.

Comment: I don't have enough privilege to do it, are there any other solutions please??

Comment: No other solution other than "wait" or "kill".  What that error is telling you is that another process is holding a lock on the resource that you're trying to use that's incompatible with the operation that you're trying to do.  You can try running again to see where the blocking shows up (specifically, which process is blocking yours), but ultimately, it needs to stop doing what it's doing for you to continue.

Answer (score 204):

In the SQL Server Management Studio,
to find out details of the active transaction, execute following command

```
DBCC opentran()
```

You will get the detail of the active transaction, then from the SPID of the active transaction, get the detail about the SPID using following commands

```
exec sp_who2 <SPID>
exec sp_lock <SPID>
```

For example, if SPID is 69 then execute the command as

```
exec sp_who2 69
exec sp_lock 69
```

Now , you can kill that process using the following command

```
KILL 69
```

Comment: The kill command would cause a rollback which may take a while.  You can use command `kill 69 with statusonly` to see the updated progress status.  You can also use command `dbcc inputbuffer(69)` to find out what SQL command was executing and caused the lock up.

Comment: KILL {process number} ==> fixed my problems. Thanks,

Answer (score 22):

It's been a while, but last time I had something similar:

```
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

or trying to

```
COMMIT
```

what had allready been done free'd everything up so I was able to clear things out and start again.

Comment: I figured out ROLLBACK TRAN/COMMIT Works if that query window is still open that caused table block, otherwise it doesn't works

Comment: Luckily I still had the window open, not sure what happens if you don't

Answer (score 4):

To prevent this, make sure every BEGIN TRANSACTION has COMMIT

The following will say successful but will leave uncommitted transactions:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRANSACTION
<SQL_CODE?
COMMIT
```

Closing query windows with uncommitted transactions will prompt you to commit your transactions. This will generally resolve the Error 1222 message.

Answer (score 0):

I had these SQL behavior settings enabled on options query execution: ANSI SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS checked. On execution of your query e.g create, alter table or stored procedure, you have to COMMIT it.

Just type COMMIT and execute it <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to disable a trigger on a table when I received error 1222 "Lock request time out period exceeded."

I followed suggestions in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179870/23720):

1. Open two query windows in SSMS.
2. In the first, type/paste the command that is timing out (due to a lock).  In the lower right hand corner of SSMS, you should see the username and (in parentheses) the SPID of the connection you're using.  Note the SPID of this query window connection.  Don't execute this query just yet.
3. In the second query window, type/paste `SELECT * FROM sysprocesses WHERE spid = <`SPID you noted in step 2`>`
4. Execute the first query that is timing out, and while it is executing (but before it times out) switch over to the second query window and execute it (the `SELECT * from sysprocesses...` one)
5. You should get some results in the results pane.  Look at the 'blocked' field in the results.  In my case, it contained the SPID of the process that was locking the table.
6. Research the locking process further by executing `SELECT * FROM sysprocesses WHERE spid = <`SPID from the 'blocked' field in step 5`>`.
7. If the locking process can be safely terminated, kill it with `kill <locking SPID>`