# Deadlock in Update Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-deadlocks

i am working on a data entry panel, there more than 300 clients working at a time with updating data on data table, i am using stored procedure to execute update in data table looks like this..

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:                <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description:        <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Tbl_Client_Bpo_Data]

@Id int,
@CId varchar(50),
@Tbc_No varchar(200),
@Name varchar(200),
@EmailId varchar(200),
@MobileNo varchar(50),
@Gender varchar(50),
@LicenseNo varchar(200),
@GirNo varchar(200),
@PanNo varchar(200),
@H_Address varchar(500),
@H_City varchar(200),
@H_PinNo varchar(200),
@H_county varchar(200),
@H_State varchar(200),
@O_Address varchar(200),
@O_City varchar(200),
@O_PinNo varchar(200),
@LAL varchar(200),
@MRNNo varchar(200),
@AF varchar(200),
@NRI varchar(200),
@CP varchar(200),
@Status varchar(200)

AS
BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;



        update Tbl_Client_Bpo_Data 
set

Tbc_No=@Tbc_No,
Name=@Name,
EmailId=@EmailId,
MobileNo=@MobileNo,
Gender=@Gender,
LicenseNo=@LicenseNo,
GirNo=@GirNo,
PanNo=@PanNo,
H_Address=@H_Address,
H_City=@H_City,
H_PinNo=@H_PinNo,
H_county=@H_county,
H_State=@H_State,
O_Address=@O_Address,
O_City=@O_City,
O_PinNo=@O_PinNo,
LAL=@LAL,
MRNNo=@MRNNo,
AF=@AF,
NRI=@NRI,
CP=@CP,
Status=@Status from  Tbl_Client_Bpo_Data  where Id=@Id and CId=@CId 
END
```

this Stored procedure get Deadlock Error like this...

```
transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. rerun the transaction.
```

i create a backup module to find error logs which displays that this stored procedure get deadlock while more clients also try to update data..
[image: Error Logs]

i also added `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`

but it doesn't work for me..
can someone give an solution to resolve this situation..

or if there is some kind of mechanism that holds execution process until previous execution completes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212255/transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-lock-resources-with-another-process-a)

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik i also added `ISOLATION LEVEL`.. i also mention this in my question

Comment: Are there indexes on your table that will be updated?

Comment: @MikeAinOz no sir, i am not updating indexes i am just use them as condition variables

Comment: You should probably look into doing [a little more investigation using tracing and the deadlock event reporting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104(v=sql.105).aspx) to make sure of what exactly is going on, i.e. is it *just* this statement conflicting with other updates using the same statement, is it within a transaction that's doing other things, what kind of lock is being held, etc. etc. This kind of investigation is quite skilled and hard to describe remotely, but you might get some advice on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/how-to-monitor-deadlocks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**

You might be missing an index on your table. First you will have to check if your update is generating a table scan, if so create one index on ID and CID to see if that solves your problem.

**Long answer**

Update statement on your table can introduce table scan. It means, that SQL Server reads every row in your table to check if row needs to be updated. During that read operation SQL Server  issues (U) update lock on the row. In case if row needs to be updated, it converts (U) lock to (X) exclusive lock and held that lock till end of transaction. (U) locks are incompatible with other (U) nor (X) locks.

In your case you have 2 sessions waiting for each other. Each session puts X lock on (different) rows and tries to issue (U) lock and read the row updated by other session (with (X) lock held). It's a bit more complicated actually - you have more than 2 sessions involved but I hope you get an idea.

Create the index to avoid table scans during update

Comment: Thank You so much, for your help. and it works, but some times it gives this error, i also added indexing to my table now it's work like charm.. thanks for your help sir