# SQL Server : Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock, hangfire

Running a stored procedure in parallel is causing the above error. The stored procedure contains `Update` and `Insert` statements. While running the stored procedure, we are getting the error

> Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

How can I run the stored procedure in parallel in separate threads and avoid the deadlock?

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM [sys].[table_types]
               WHERE user_type_id = Type_id(N'[dbo].[ClassTableType]'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ClassTableType] AS TABLE (DisplayName NVARCHAR(256));
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CreateUpdateClasses] 
    (@ClassTVPList ClassTableType READONLY)
AS 
    UPDATE t1
    SET DisplayName = t2.DisplayName
    FROM TargetTable t1
    INNER JOIN @ClassTVPList t2 ON t1.ColumnId = t2.ColumnId 
                                AND t1.TenantId = t2.TenantId

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO TargetTable (DisplayName)
            SELECT * FROM @ClassTVPList;
```

Comment: Have you tried the TABLELOCK hint?

INSERT INTO TargetTable(DisplayDame) WITH (ROWLOCK) VALUES(...)

Comment: It's a good thing you have a deadlock because this is an inherently unsafe way to do this. First step would be rewriting that to a [`merge` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), then applying lock hints to it [as appropriate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/183409/5203).

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212255/transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-lock-resources-with-another-process-a