# How to handle deadlocks when using C# Entity Framework Database First code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deadlock, ef-database-first, database-deadlocks

A common issue I have been running into deadlock exceptions since I'm running constant select statements and update statements via entity framework every second. So here is a simple example of one of the common methods my program uses to pull data from my database:

```
public static List<T>? HandleNetworkTaskToList<T, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereStatement, Func<T, TKey> orderByStatement, OrderByDirection direction, int takeCount) where T : class
{
     using var context = new dbContext();

     return direction == OrderByDirection.Ascending ? context.Set<T>().Where(whereStatement).OrderBy(orderByStatement).Take(takeCount).ToList()
     : context.Set<T>().Where(whereStatement).OrderByDescending(orderByStatement).Take(takeCount).ToList();

}
```

This is the exception message:

> "Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."

I found [a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27899713/3610374) to this common issue but I'm unsure of how to incorporate this solution since I'm using the Entity Framework with Database First mode.

Does anyone have a working example for how I can run my code on the database side like the solution above seems to suggest while using my existing code methods or does anyone have a working example where I can replicate the same behavior on the client side?