# Lock request time out period exceeded when running long update script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I tried to find something similar, but couldn't so decided to ask directly.

I'm running long bulk update script which is updating ~50m records. The updated is broken in batches, with checkpoints to allow clearing the transaction log. Tried to run the script two times now, the first time it broke after updating roughly 17m rows, the second time it stopped at 14m.

Error message: Msg 1222, Level 16, State 43, Line 122
Lock request time out period exceeded

Here is the pseudo code:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE #Update (
    I_ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    PrimaryKeyID bigint NOT NULL,
    UpdateValue int
)

DECLARE @RecordsToUpdate int
DECLARE @ChunkCount int = 25000
DECLARE @CommitCount int = 100000
DECLARE @CheckpointCount int = 500000

-- Populate the whole table and values. 
...
-- Update the data. 
WHILE @RecordsUpdated < @RecordsToUpdate 
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRecordsToUpdate = @RecordsUpdated + @ChunkCount

    UPDATE RealTable
    SET Val = UpdateVal
    FROM #Update
        INNER JOIN RealTable ON RealTable.PrimaryKeyID = #Update.PrimaryKeyID
    WHERE #Update.I_ID BETWEEN @RecordsUpdated AND @CurrentRecordsToUpdate

    SET @RecordsUpdated = @CurrentRecordsToUpdate

    IF @RecordsUpdated % @CheckpointCount = 0
    BEGIN
        CHECKPOINT
    END

    IF @RecordsUpdated % @CommitCount = 0
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
    END

END

COMMIT TRAN
```

I ran it on another database where the number of rows is smaller (~20m)and it ran just fine. Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated. It's highly unlikely that it was clashing with another transaction, as the system was brought down for the update. 
p.s. It's on SQL Server 2014 if it matters.

Comment: "it broke" - The actual error message would be useful, since it sounds like some resource is being exhausted.

Comment: @Turophile Sorry, the error message is in the Subject: Msg 1222, Level 16, State 43, Line 122
Lock request time out period exceeded. Added to the body. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that something else *is* accessing your table while you are updating it. Try the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258710/how-to-solve-sql-server-error-1222-i-e-unlock-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's yet uncertain whether this was the issue or not, but after reviewing SSMS settings Query Execution > Advanced, I found that SET Lock Timeout parameter was set to a value of 10000. Good chances that updating it to -1 might resolve the issue.